# Differentiate between scrollToIndex and manual scroll in React Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `FlatList` that automatically scrolls item by item based on a time series using the `scrollToIndex` function. I also want to let the user scroll the list by themselves and temporarily disable the automatic scroll when this happens.
My idea was to use the `onScroll` event to catch when the user scrolls the list and set a boolean flag. The problem is that the `onScroll` event gets triggered also by `scrollToIndex`.
Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a method called “onMomentumScrollEnd” which should be unique to touch interactions. With it you can debounce or disable your timer. You’ll have to test whether or not your timed scrollToIndex function will have the ability to take precedence over the users interaction though. In the case that it does you’ll have to add a PanResponder to the containing view and disable/debounce your timer from within its “onPanResponderGrant” method.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround can be using a flag set (say using this.disableOnScrollEvent = true of the component class)

```
function onScrollToIndexHandler() {
   this.disableOnScrollEvent = true
   // remaining code
}

function onScrollEventHandler(event){
  if(this.disableOnScrollEvent){
     this.disableOnScrollEvent = false;
      return;
  }
 // remaining code
}
```